# Sticky footer at bottom without having content in body overlap

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky footer that sticks to the bottom, but the problem is the contents in the body and the footer overlap.

I currently have my html, body, and main set to height 100% / min-height: 100%, but and my footer is positioned absolute with left: 0 and bottom: 0. The problem with this is, I have my background image positioned at the bottom of my main and it overlaps onto the positioned absolute footer.

I also tried not having my footer positioned absolute and just have the main height 100%, and this works fine, but I have to scroll down to see the footer. Why is the footer being pushed down so much that I need to scroll down? I want the footer to be exactly at the bottom of the page without having to scroll down to see it.

```
<html>
   <body>
     <main>
       <div>Contents here</div>
     </main>
     <footer/>
   </body>
</html>


html, body, main {
   height: 100%;
}
.content {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-y: 100%;
    background-position-x: center;
    background-size: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: that does not seem to work when it is positioned absolute. When I do not have it positoned absolute, it stick to bottom and margin bottom is not necessary, but I need to scroll down to see the footer. I do not understand why the footer is going down to exceed the height of my browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is sticky footer code that works. You might want to use this layout to solve your issue.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
}
.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1>Sticky Footer with Negative Margin 1</h1>
  <p><button id="add">Add Content</button></p>
  <div class="push"></div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  Footer 
</footer>
```

Comment: My background image I have set in my content is still overlapping the footer. I have added css for my background image to my original post

Comment: try display:block

Comment: Display block on the div? I thought div was block by default

Comment: sometimes you need to specify it